# Trajectories of Free Particle in (3+1) Dimension

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, spacetime, gauss-law, spacetime-dimensions

It is often mentioned that due to long range attractive forces in 4D spacetimes, the particle trajectory at large time t looks like:
$$r(t) = v*(t+ c_1 \ln(t)).$$

I'm interested in understanding how this comes and why it's just true in (3+1)D. Also is there a generalization to non-flat spacetimes?

Comment: Why does your title say “free particle” while your body says “attractive forces”? These are incompatible.

Comment: I said "free" because I'm looking at large time behaviour. and it's mentioned for instance https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.09193  eqn 4.5

Answer (score 3):

This formula (which I had never seen before) is the asymptotic behavior for large $t$ of classical scattering trajectories under any attractive inverse-square force. The relevant differential equation is

$$\ddot{\mathbf{r}}=-\alpha\frac{\mathbf{r}}{r^3}.$$

It is well-known that the bound solutions are ellipses. It is also well-known that scattering solutions are hyperbolas. Less well-known is their time dependence, which can be found in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_orbit#Properties_of_trajectory_equation).

If the scattering trajectory is taken to be in the $z$-plane, and the $x$-axis is taken as its axis of symmetry, then the trajectory can be parameterized as

$$x(E)=a(\epsilon-\cosh{E}),$$

$$y(E)=a(\epsilon^2-1)^{1/2}\sinh{E},$$

$$t(E)=\frac{a^{3/2}}{\alpha^{1/2}}(\epsilon\sinh{E}-E).$$

Here the length $a$ and the eccentricity $\epsilon$ completely characterize the trajectory.

The parameter $E$ along the trajectory is called the "eccentric anomaly". (It is not an energy.) Note that $x$, $y$, and $t$ are all simple functions of $E$.

It is a somewhat tedious exercise to verify that this parameterized trajectory satisfies the differential equation. (You need to express the time derivatives in terms of derivatives with respect to $E$.)

It is *not* possible to express $x$ and $y$ simply and exactly in terms of $t$, but we can find the claimed asymptotic relationship between $r=(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$ and $t$ for large $t$.

Using

$$\cosh{u}=\frac12(e^u+e^{-u})$$

and

$$\sinh{u}=\frac12(e^u-e^{-u}),$$

we have the following approximations for large $E$, which corresponds to large $t$:

$$x\approx -\frac{a}{2}e^E+O(E^0),$$

$$y\approx\frac{a(\epsilon^2-1)^{1/2}}{2}e^E+O(e^{-E}),$$

$$t\approx\frac{a^{3/2}}{\alpha^{1/2}}\left(\frac{\epsilon}{2}e^E-E+O(e^{-E})\right).$$

From these it follows that

$$r\approx\frac{\epsilon a}{2}e^E+O(E^0),$$

$$\ln{t}\approx E+O(E^0),$$

and

$$t+\frac{a^{3/2}}{\alpha^{1/2}}\ln{t}\approx\frac{\epsilon a^{3/2}}{2\alpha^{1/2}}e^E+O(E^0).$$

Thus we find the claimed asymptotic behavior,

$$r(t)\approx\frac{\alpha^{1/2}}{a^{1/2}}t+a\ln{t}+...$$

In other dimensions, the scattering trajectories would be different. But I don't know what they are and thus I don't know what the asymptotic behavior would be.